# Can not interface with Winbond W25Q16DVSIG over SPI

Tags: atmega, spi, flash

I'm trying to attach Winbond W25Q16DVSIG to Atmega 1284P-PU. I've attached SPI bus according to the pinout, CS pin has 10K pullup resistor.

Whenever I'm trying to perform any operation, chip is not responding. I've wrote very simple code to be able to test read of manufacturer / device id using instruction 90h according to the [datasheet](https://www.winbond.com/resource-files/w25q16dv_revi_nov1714_web.pdf) page 52

Basically it require to send four bytes, one with instruction 90h followed by 24bit address (all zero).

When I'm trying to get response, I'm always getting zeros (two bytes).

Code is very simple and looks like this

```
    byte data [4];
    data[0] = 0x90;
    data[1] = 0x00;
    data[2] = 0x00;
    data[3] = 0x00;

    digitalWrite(FLASH_CS, LOW);
    SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(10000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));

    SPI.transfer(data, 4);

    byte data1 = SPI.transfer(0x00);
    byte data2 = SPI.transfer(0x00);

    SPI.endTransaction();
    digitalWrite(FLASH_CS, HIGH);
```

I've checked transfer with LA, and it looks like chip is not responding at all (there are some strange two spikes). It looks like this:

[image]

I've done the same for Winbond W25Q16BVSIG and it is working fine. I'm getting proper response and transmission looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here ? Is there something I'm missing from the datasheet ? SPI Clock is too slow ?

Wiring is the same for both chips. Unfortunately I don't have any programmer to check flash chip directly.

Comment: Confirm that the "/Hold" pin is not inadvertently pulled low (pin 7 on the SOIC8 version).  See Page 10 of the listed datasheet.

Comment: /Hold and /WP pins are pulled directly to VCC (3.3V)

Comment: have u tried reducing the speed to may be 1Mhz and see any change in response?

Comment: Without any better ideas, I'll state the obvious: quadtriple-check that the MISO pin is properly configured as input, or MISO-mode, or whatever the ATMega needs for SPI.  It certainly looks as if something is holding that line high.  Check the regs during operation and confirm.  Bad Winbond chip?:  Lift the MISO pin on the chip and connect to a scope.

Comment: It turns out that chip was faulty. I've replaced it with another one, everything is fine. Many thanks for help! P.S. I should have started with that :)